# Are TRUE and FALSE defined in headers of xlc_r AIX compiler?

Tags: aix, xlc

I am porting some code from AIX to Linux I am getting compilations errors for undefined symbols TRUE and FALSE. They are not defined in the source code and I dont have access to AIX system. Are these symbols defined in headers of xlc compiler ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, TRUE and FALSE are defined in some headers on AIX (unrelated to xlc though). Examples: cur01.h, curses.h, im.h, ntbl.h, piostruct.h, IN/standard.h, rpc/types.h, sys/audio.h